# If requirement in string is met make a sum of column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to make a sum of currency from column D if the name of the party in column G is `MOBILE-FOR HASSELT`. I tried:

```
=SUMIF(D4:D250;E4:E250="MOBILE-FOR HASSELT")
```

and then CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER but I can only see `0`.

[image: https://gyazo.com/4c05d7bae30a71789cc17f1dd603a66a]

Comment: 1) You probably do not have enough spaces between `MOBILE-FOR` and `HASSELT` in your formula.  The data shows more than one.  2) The formula is not an array formula and does not need the Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: I have 6 spaces in that field, but it still won't work...

Comment: sorry missed the equals in the formula, it should be: `=SUMIF(D4:D250;E4:E250;"MOBILE-FOR HASSELT")`

Comment: @pnuts In my head I was doing SUMIFS.  I hate that those two have differing criteria orders.

Comment: Shouldn't the criteria range be `G4:G250` instead of `E4:E250` as per example sheet in OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not the best way to accomplish it by any means, but if your spreadsheet allows for it you can add a helper cell to the right of column G and link the value to the cell in column D. then using the typical formula          =SUMIF(D4:D250,"MOBILE-FOR   HASSELT",H4:H250)

depending on the spreadsheet i have used it for years.... mind you if you sort your data it can get messy on occasion though...

i would have added it to the comments but i don't have that ability yet